# "It's the second country I live in" vs. "it's the second country I'm living in"

Tags: difference, present-continuous, present-simple

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> It's the second country **I live** in and I don't think I'll leave it anytime soon.
>
> It's the second country **I am living** in and I don't think I'll leave it anytime soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are odd, (though grammatically correct)

The reason they are odd is that they refer to your present countries.  They mean that you are living in two countries now  (or that you always live in two countries). Most people only live in one country.  You probably want to use

> This is the second country that I have lived in.

You are talking about your present experience resulting from living in two countries It implies that you have left one country and are currently living in the second.